# Не могу скачать файл по ссылке

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import urllib.request

destination = 'test'
url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/953392557054918697/a_e778ada2e5c10f0f7f6b256159bd29a3.gif?size=1024'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, destination)
```

Ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\bot-main\q.py", line 5, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, destination)
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 241, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\xlvlo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

Answer (score 1):

читайте ошибку. С википедии

> HTTP 403 Forbidden — стандартный код ответа HTTP, означающий, что доступ к запрошенному ресурсу запрещен.

[Здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_403) можно подробнее прочесть.

копать в сторону авторизации/аутентификации с проверкой всех сущностей, которые отправляются в запросе.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/953392557054918697/a_e778ada2e5c10f0f7f6b256159bd29a3.gif?size=1024'
res = requests.get(url)
with open("1.gif", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(res.content)
```